# @HTML.editorForModel() doesn't create editing interface for Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, editorformodel

I have a model:
Menu is subClass of menuComponent

and menu component has two properties: Name and Description both are string

I have created an Edit View and tried to create editing fields with editorForModel().
but it doesn't create any editing fields for it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorForModel();
    <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index") 
}
```

I have to use @HTML.EditorFor() to create editing fileds

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name);
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description);
        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index") 
    }
```

why this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug that I reported to Microsoft: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636341/modelmetadata-fromlambdaexpression-has-changed-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rtm

Basically Editor and Display templates only look for properties on the exact current type of your model, not in parent classes.

Their official answer is this:

> Hi Darin (and others),
>
> This was a deliberate change that we introduced to ASP.NET MVC 3 that
>   was the result of a trade-off between having better support for
>   inherited models or better support for models that implement
>   interfaces. We ended up favoring inherited models, which from our
>   experience is a more common approach.
>
> The fundamental problem is that when an interface is implemented by a
>   class that the class doesn't *really* inherit any of the members of
>   the interface. The key here is that because it doesn't inherit the
>   members of the interface, it also does not inherit the metadata on
>   those members.
>
> Thanks, The ASP.NET Team

So basically they do not consider it as a bug but it is by design.

Comment: what do they mean about the MEMBER OF INTERFACE?

Comment: I guess it's a property that is defined in an interface that your model implements.

Comment: why they mean my class can't inherit the properties? as I can implement them in my class!!

Comment: They mean that properties that are declared in an interface (that your class implements without any problems) are not taken into account by the Editor and Display helpers. It is the behavior you are observing.